# load dependency to angularjs app after bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have angular js 1.3.3 app.

I'm loading a module from other website with :

> RequireJS

I want to bootstrap my application and then load the external module Immediately after.

My code :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.run(function(){
   // Load external module 
   require("some js url", function(){
      app.requires.push("externalApp");
    });
});
angular.bootstrap($("html"), "myApp");
```

This code is not working (In "myApp" there not access to services from the "externalApp"), What's wrong ?

Would appreciate help, Thanks a lot

Refa.

Comment: Are you creating or just referencing your module "myApp" there?

Comment: just referencing the create it's done before @tiagodws

Answer (score 0):

The `require` call of RequireJS is asynchronous. By the time `angular.bootstrap` executes, there's no guarantee that `app.requires.push(...)` will have run. In fact, it is extremely likely it won't have run because the `require` call presumably entails loading a module from somewhere, and that takes time.

You should restructure your code so that the `require` is outside so that you are sure that `app.requires.push(...)` runs before you bootstrap your application.

```
require("some js url", function () {
  var app = angular.module("myApp");
  app.run(function () {
    // Load external module 
    app.requires.push("externalApp");
  });
  angular.bootstrap($("html"), "myApp");
});
```

Comment: but i want to up the application before that I loading the external module after the angular.bootstrap